# Button Moving when Table is Inserted

Tags: html, css, button, css-tables

Here is my button in my Html:

```
<div id="Home">
<FORM>
<INPUT Type="BUTTON" Value="Home" Onclick="window.location.href='NBA.htm'"> 
</FORM>
</div>
```

And this is the Positioning I gave it in CSS:

```
#Home {
position:absolute;
transition: .5s ease;
top: 0px;
left: 0px;
right: -420px;
bottom: -191px;
}
```

Everything works fine, but as soon as I add a Table with border everything sorta screws up :(

Without the Table the button is in the top left of the page like i want it to be, but as sson as I add a table with a border, the Button moves into the top of my text field...

My text in CSS:

```
#Text {
position: absolute;
background-image: url("http://support.leagueapps.com/customer/portal/attachments/28383");
color: #3399ff;
border-color: Lightblue;
border-style: double;
border-width: 5px;
top: 160px;
left: 150px;
height: 1500px;
width: 900px;
font-size: 13pt;
font-family: Franklin Gothic Medium;
padding-top: 10px;
padding-bottom: 10px;
padding-left: 10px;
padding-right: 10px;
box-shadow: 10px 10px 10px grey;
border-radius: 20px;
}
```

Any ideas on how I can stop my Button from moving but still be able to make a table with border...?

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like this?

```css
.main button {
position: fixed;
top: 0;
left: 0;
transition: .5s ease;
}
table td {
border: 2px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <form>
    <button type="submit">Home</button>
  </form>
</div>
<br/>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Blah</td>
    <td>Blah</td>
    <td>Blah</td>
    <td>Blah</td>
    <td>Blah</td>
    <td>Blah</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Blah</td>
    <td>Blah</td>
    <td>Blah</td>
    <td>Blah</td>
    <td>Blah</td>
    <td>Blah</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Blah</td>
    <td>Blah</td>
    <td>Blah</td>
    <td>Blah</td>
    <td>Blah</td>
    <td>Blah</td>
  </tr>
```